# Is it safe to expose the UserId to a client?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm developing a web app and I'm wondering if exposing `UserId`s to the clients is potentially posing a security vulnerability. (By `UserId` I refer to the `Id` of an Identity user object created by the Identity Framework and used as a PK of the users table.)

To give some context or an example: in my app, I need to distinguish between content that is posted by the signed in user and the content that was posted by others. In a naive approach, I would just compare the `UserId` of the content to the `UserId` of the currently authenticated user. But that would mean that the client sees the Ids of all involved users.

My gut feeling tells me that this is not a good idea but I couldn't pinpoint to why. So, I wonder if there's a guideline around this question. Maybe it's just the general rule to reduce the surface of knowledge that is exposed to a minimum.

If this is the case, how should I proceed? Would hashing of the `UserId` help to solve the problem or are there better approaches around?

**EDIT**

The example I made is not the best because this problem can easily be solved on the back-end by comparing user IDs there and then sending the contents to the client already tagged as "mine" or "by others". But still, the general question remains.

Comment: [Security.se] is a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If user IDs are themselves sensitive data,for example, your primary keys for some reason happen to be social security numbers, that'll definitely be a security and privacy liability. If your user IDs are just auto-increment numbers though, it should be fine.

It is always best to expose a unique identifier other than the primary key outside your system. It gives you more flexibility in resolving data mix-ups, dealing with data migration issues, and in otherwise future-proofing your system.

If UIDs are just identifiers for users. Knowing a user's UID does not grant you any permissions that are associated with that user. Sharing the UID in URLs is about as safe as sharing your username on Github, or your unique ID on Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow displays user IDs in their URLs in order to make user profile lookups work: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10158551/xing-zou

Anyway, it is up to your design and you need to consider more than we could.

Refer to [Should I expose a user ID to public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629134/should-i-expose-a-user-id-to-public)

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not a good idea to expose the user id at the client-side. If you need any information, username or a unique number is better than the exact user id in the database. This is generally not an issue if your application has protections against SQL injection attacks. But in case there is any vulnerability in loopholes, if anyone knows the user id for a user, they can inject SQL scripts for that user. 
A better idea is to issue an access token to your clients with claims inside that. The access token will perform authentication for you on the server-side.

Comment: Authentication is not the problem here. It's about client-side business logic that need to compare users in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in the low risk category. Exposing user ids does increase the risk surface as you have correctly identified.

For you application, it sounds like you require an identifier for the post and an indication of whether that post has been made by the user or by someone else.

You could structure that in the following way to avoid the low risk exposure:

```
GET /posts

{
  "postId": "AJDIWC",
  "isAuthor": true,
  "content": "This is a post by the user."
},
{
  "postId": "LISHWE",
  "isAuthor": false,
  "content": "This is a post by another user."
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer your question following the edit, yes, it is best practice to avoid exposing identifiers from other users unless the authorisation boundary allows it.

For example, there is no issue having an admin user of an RBAC protected application see the unique identifiers of users within their security boundary.

Comment: Yes, that's my EDIT :)